# Losing session after HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

I read "[How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)",  added `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `django.contrib.sessions` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and tried the following in my view:

```
if not request.session.get('confirmed_disclaimer', False):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DisclaimerForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['confirmed_disclaimer'] = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect('.')
    else:
        form = DisclaimerForm()
else:
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect('.')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm(request)
return render_to_response('login.html', {'form': form, },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This should show a disclaimer form first and the login form after, if not already confirmed once (session). But im losing the session after `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Do I using it wrong?

Thx for any advise!

**EDIT**

had a

```
...
logout(request)
return login(request)
```

in a Mixin. This created a new session everytime, sorry and thx for trying to help @DrTyrsa!

Comment: And may be your `DisclaimerForm` is just not valid? Don't you handle this case?

Comment: this works. because `form` has errors after initialize with `request.POST`

Comment: every reload gives me another `sessionid`, may this be the problem?

Comment: Have you run `manage.py syncdb` anfter added `django.contrib.sessions`?

Comment: yes, did that. maybe it's a problem because i'm using this as an application content in feincms. i'll edit my post, if so.

Comment: oh got it... had a

    ...
    logout(request)
    return login(request)

in a Mixin. This created a new session everytime, sorry and thx for trying to help @DrTyrsa!